# Foreign keys and indexes

Tags: mysql, indexing, foreign-keys

I have 2 tables: *products* and *categories*. Each category has many products, and a product can belong to many categories.

**products**

```
product_id - int primary auto increment
name - unique
etc.
```

**categories**

```
category_id - int primary auto increment
name - unique
etc.
```

I have a 3rd table for manyTomany relations.

**products_categories**

```
product_id -> foreign key: products.product_id
category_id -> foreign key: category.category_id
```

My question is: should I create indexes for `product_id` and `category_id` in **product_categories** for faster select queries, and if yes, what indexes?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on which queries will be the most frequent.

You may end up with three indexes.

1. If you have `... WHERE products_categories.product_id = XXX`, create an index on `product_id`.
2. Same for `category_id`
3. Create an index on both `category_id` *and* `product_id` if you have `... WHERE products_categories.category_id = XXX AND products_categories.product_id = YYY`

However, [following the MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html), keep in mind that an index on `(category_id, product_id)` may be redundant with an index on `(category_id)`. As well,  an index on `(product_id, category_id)` may be redundant with an index on `(product_id)`. So you may finally end up with two indexes (instead of three) covering all your frequent query needs.

Comment: just to say that, you should stick to one way: either make a query category_id AND product_id , or the other way around. Then you will need only one compound index and you might add a second simple one

Comment: Thank you for explanation, and for introducing me to multiple column indexes.

Answer (score 1):

You definitly should create indices, as the FOREIGN KEY constraint says nothing about the source field for the constraint, so it doesn't auto-create an index.

For the question "which index" you ofcourse do not want a unique index - and I'd stick with a default index which is BTREE.

Comment: Thank you for this: FOREIGN KEY constraint says nothing about the source field for the constraint.