# Should these Mysql foreign keys also have index assigned

Tags: php, mysql, join, indexing, foreign-keys

I have 3 tables. **Product**, **Category**, **User**

**Category** has a primary key called **c_id**

**User** has a primary key called **u_id**

The **Product** table has 2 `FOREIGN KEYs`. **cat_id** and **seller_id**

**cat_id** refers to **c_id** in the Category table and **seller_id** refers to **u_id** in the User table.

Is this the right way to do it?

In order to make a `INNER JOIN` so that I can get the sellers name for the product and the category name for the product?

Ofc, each product can only have one seller and category.

Should I also add a `index key` to the `FOREIGN KEYs`? Or does a `FOREIGN KEY` count as a index?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Foreign keys and indexes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8910431/foreign-keys-and-indexes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This is the right way.
Also if you want to use referential integrity you should make these fields as index keys that is  **cat_id** and **seller_id** in **Product** table.